# How to add a face connecting two meshes

Tags: mesh, faces

I am trying to make a die.
I managed to do the "frame" and pips. Pips are separate from frame, but same object (Ctrl J).
How i can add a face connecting frame with pips, but leave pips as they are?
When i select edges as in picture and add a face (F) pips also have separate face on them. Removing that pip-face does not help - i still do not see pips.
Blend file is here (although it is really simple...): http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45646
[image: How to add face to my die?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest another approach. It needs some calculation at the beginning to handle correctly where the holes are to be placed, but it does so your final shape has no 'ngons' (faces with more than 4 vertices) which is always better.

The principle is to start with a plane, and give it some symmetrical loop cuts in order to place the future holes :

[image]

Now we want to make one hole (this one will be duplicated after that) :

- Select a place for the future hole
- Inset <kbd>I</kbd> and move the mouse to scale/place the inset faces
- Select the outer vertices and make them circular <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
- Scale a bit to adjust

[image]

- Now extrude <kbd>E</kbd> the inner part

[image]

Add a subdivision surface modifier to check the result and eventually refine it (add some bevel for instance, if needed).

[image]

Once done, all is matter of duplicating the hole and merge the six faces.

Make each die's face by duplicating the initial hole :

- Delete a vertex to make a place for the hole
- Select the hole
- Set the snapping mode to vertex
- Duplicate the hole and place it
- Once done, select all and remove doubles

[image]

Do that for the six faces and reassembly all in a complete die :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good idea :) I did the faces of die with pips. But how to connect them into one mesh afterwards?

Comment: To join 2 (or more meshes), use ctrl+J. In the case of the die, you'll have to remove doubles after that)

Comment: I ment how did you connected all faces and achieved rounded corners :) Joining meshes into one object is known to me. Thank You lemon!

Comment: The rounded corners are obtained thanks to the subsurface modifier. And for connecting faces (if I understand your question), simply rotate and place the individual faces join them and remove doubles. Or I did not understand what you are asking?

Comment: Got it! I applied sussurface mod before joining faces of die - my bad. Now all looks cool when i first connected everything and afterwards applied susurface modifier.! Thank You!

Comment: Applying the subsurf, generally, the later is better!