# How to cut circles out of the cube?

Tags: objects, knife-tool

[image]

I am making some quick sketch of the dice. I need to make inner part of the circle leave a trace inside dice and with the outer part completely gone. How to make that?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305056/rounded-dice-why-do-the-simplest-things-seem-so-difficult https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107584/creating-a-cleaner-uv-map-for-dice https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74137/how-to-add-a-face-connecting-two-meshes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223607/boolean-is-not-working-correctly-when-trying-to-subtract-a-collection